# How to access HttpSession data from Dart HttpServer WebSocket?

Tags: session, websocket, dart

I have a very simple WebSocket server:

```dart
class WsServer {
  WsServer();

  void runServer(int port) {
    ConnectionsHandler connectionsHandler = new ConnectionsHandler();

    HttpServer
      .bind('127.0.0.1', port)
      .then((HttpServer server) {
        print('listening for connections on $port');

        var sc = new StreamController();
        sc.stream.transform(new WebSocketTransformer()).listen(connectionsHandler.onConnection);

        server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
          if (request.uri.path == '/ws') {
            sc.add(request);
          }
          // we dont deal static files
        });
      },
      onError: (error) => print("Error starting HTTP server: $error"));
  }
}

class ConnectionsHandler {
  List<WebSocket> connections = new List<WebSocket>();

  ConnectionsHandler();

  void onConnection(WebSocket conn) {
    print('new ws conn');
    connections.add(conn);
    conn.listen(
      onMessage,
      onDone: () => connections.remove(conn),
      onError: (e) => connections.remove(conn)
    );
  }

  void onMessage(message) {
    print('new ws msg: $message');
  } 
}
```

I need to get `request.session` in `ConnectionsHandler`. `WebSocketTransformer` seems to send only`WebSocket` connection which doesn't have access to original `HttpRequest` with session.

Is there way to access session data from websocket handler itself? Even if client send dart session id from cookie, how to retrieve and refresh HttpSession then?

Comment: I rolled out my own implementation of session support for this reason. It was the simplest and quickest solution I could do in a short time and it's working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to get this to work, but you can only see the cookies, and thus the session, if the web socket connection uses the same origin as the normal HTTP requests.

Note that `WebSocketTransformer` doesn't have to be used in a stream. You can upgrade one request at a time.

Can you try the following code?

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

class WsServer {
  WsServer();

  void runServer(int port) {
    ConnectionsHandler connectionsHandler = new ConnectionsHandler();

    HttpServer
      .bind('127.0.0.1', port)
      .then((HttpServer server) {
        print('listening for connections on $port');
        var connHandler = new ConnectionsHandler();
        var webSocketTransformer = new WebSocketTransformer();

        server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
          if (request.uri.path == '/ws') {
            webSocketTransformer.upgrade(request)
              .then((WebSocket ws) {
                connHandler.onConnection(ws, request);
              });
            // TODO handle error from update
          }
          // we dont deal static files
        });
      },
      onError: (error) => print("Error starting HTTP server: $error"));
  }
}

class ConnectionsHandler {
  List<WebSocket> connections = new List<WebSocket>();

  ConnectionsHandler();

  void onConnection(WebSocket conn, HttpRequest req) {
    print('new ws conn');
    connections.add(conn);
    conn.listen(
      (message) {
        print('new ws msg: $message and ${req.session.keys}');
      },
      onDone: () => connections.remove(conn),
      onError: (e) => connections.remove(conn)
    );
  }
}

main() {
  var server = new WsServer();
  server.runServer(3000);
}
```